# Why does my Regexp-Code not show html code?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I would like to change something like `<var title="some text">Something</var>` to `<abbr title="some text">Something</abbr>`. I have this code, but somehow it does not show the abbr tag on my webpage:

```
$arr[0] = preg_replace("#<var(.*?)>(.*?)</var>#", "<abbr $1>$2</abbr>", "".$arr[0]."");
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What's the # symbol for?

Comment: Did you assign the return value to a variable?  It does not do the replacement in place.

Comment: @Geoff It's a delimiter. They can be many different things, not just `/pattern/`

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski: yes I did, changed it in the code now

Comment: A quick test and this works perfectly for me.  Lose the `"".$arr[0].""` concatenation nonsense though.

Comment: http://codepad.viper-7.com/eWqycI

Comment: By the way, before someone else comes along with a snarky remark about it, it is really not recommended to process HTML with regular expressions. You'll be able to accomplish more with a real DOM parser like Simple html dom or DOMDocument.

Comment: @Michael is right. Your regex will fail with this input: `<var title=">">Something</var>`, whereas a DOM parser will not.

Comment: Ok I think I know the reason why it doesn't work. Inside the title tag, there are brackets like `<var title="some text (with brackets)">`. How could I escape them?

Comment: @phpheini - Use a DOM paser, it'll solve all of your problems. Will you consider an answer using one, or are you committed to using a regex?

Comment: Well does it really make sense to use a DOM parser when I will only use preg_replace once in my whole script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you should use an HTML parser, and avoid using a regex to parse HTML:

```
// Load the HTML into the parser
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadHTML( '<var title="some text">Something</var>');

// Find the <var> tags, and create new <abbr> tags from them.
foreach( $doc->getElementsByTagName( 'var') as $var) {
    $abbr = $doc->createElement( 'abbr', $var->textContent);
    $abbr->setAttribute( 'title', $var->getAttribute( 'title'));
    echo $doc->saveHTML( $abbr); // Here is your new <abbr> tag
}
```

You can see from [this demo](http://viper-7.com/E7OBa3) that this produces:

```
<abbr title="some text">Something</abbr>
```

Comment: Which html parser is this?

Comment: So i don't need to include a parser class?

Comment: Nope, as long as your host has DOMDocument installed / enabled (which, if the above code runs and works, they do).

Answer (score 0):

Change `"<abbr $1>$2</abbr>"`  to `'<abbr $1>$2</abbr>'` (Notice the single quotes).

See [single quoted strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single).